# Fine-Uploader php installation directory

Tags: php, installation, directory, fine-uploader

I just installed the php version of fine-uploader.
I installed it to the folder in my root called fineuploader

When I go to the admin panel, I login ok and then on the page mydomain/fineuploader/admin/settings/users it lists Admin as the only user. But
the link shown for each of the clickable fields are: mydomain/admin/settings/users/admin
mydomain/admin/settings/users/admin/edit
mydomain/admin/settings/users/admin/delete
 (which all give a not found)

I assume it should be for example mydomain/fineuploader/admin/settings/users/admin (though I don't see a folder mydomain/fineuploader/admin/settings/users/ on my server either).

What do I need to change to tell the fineuploader php software that I have installed it in the directory mydomain/fineuploader/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Response just received from Fine-Uploader support:

"At this time, due to resource limitations, we are not able to provide the same support for Fine Uploader PHP that we have consistently provided for the JavaScript library. Fine Uploader PHP is in a beta state at the moment. We have decided to shelve Fine Uploader PHP until we are able to secure enough developers to provide consistent support and evolution of that product."